# How do I best save a transform to a file?

Tags: rosbag, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since it seems the rosbag C++ API doesn't work very well with the tf library, and I cannot find a simple way of saving ROS datatypes to files, I don't know how to best save a transform that I have calculated. I really need something that maintains the datatype, so that I won't need to make my own functions just to separately read position and orientation and so forth.

For what it's worth, I am considering using just a geometry_msgs::Quaternion and a geometry_msgs::Point and recreating the transform from those data. Any other recommendations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185895/how-do-i-best-save-a-transform-to-a-file?/) by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2014-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is `geometry_msgs::Pose` for that that already contains a pose and orientation.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1